# Find the number of matrices such that $Tr(A)$ is not divisible by $p$ but $Det(A)$ divisible by $p$

Tags: matrices, number-theory, prime-numbers, determinant

If $p$ is an Odd prime and Given $$S= \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
a &b \\ 
 c& a
\end{bmatrix} :a,b,c \in \left\{0,1,2,3,\cdots, p-1\right\}\right\}$$

Find number of Matrices in $S$ such that $Tr(A)$ is not divisible by $p$ but $Det(A)$ divisible by $p$

My Try:

$Tr(A)=2a$

Obviously $Tr(A)$ is not divisible by $p$ when $a \ne 0$ and so $ 1 \le a \le p-1$

Now $$|A|=a^2-bc$$ should be divisible by $p$ i.e.,

$$a^2 \equiv bc (mod)p \tag{1}$$

Let $b=c$ Then  $$|A|=a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)=mp$$ for some integer $m$

so either $a=b$ or $(a,b)=(1,p-1)$ OR $(a,b)=(2,p-2)$ and so on

So total  $2(p-1)$ ordered pairs.

But any clue for proceeding with $ b \ne c$

Comment: Hint: either $b$ and $c$ are both quadratic residues or they are both non-residues.

Comment: Can you please be more specific

Comment: So you mean to say for fixed $a$ and $b$ we get only one $c$ such that $a^2 \equiv bc (mod)p $, but i am unable to prove it formally